# what's the nicest way to run multiple JDKs on windows for running different programs with the right JVM?

Tags: 64-bit, java, 32-bit

I need to run some java programs in a 32 bit JVM and some in 64. I'm wondering if there's a better way than writing scripts to start them?

Comment: How do you *want* to start them in an ideal world?

Comment: Well using standard installers always goes for the most recently installed JDK probably. I'm just looking for a personal productivity top really in the end, because it's a bit of hassle to go through the process for each program, associating icons etc. And what about java based shell extensions?

Comment: Ah, you want to double-click an icon - sorry, that wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use full path to 32-bit and 64-bit java executable:
`C:\Program Files\JDK64bit\bin\java.exe -cp .  your.jar`
  You may wrap it into platform dependent exe